# Listing files in a directory recursively - python

Tags: python, directory, python-2.6

I want to display file and folder structure recursively in output .

**Actual Structure:**

```
Root--|
      |
      DIRA--|
            |
            DIRC--File5
            File3
            File4
      File1
      File2
      DIRB--|
            |
            No File
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Root:
File1
File2

Root/DIRA
File3
File4

Root/DIRA/DIRC
File5


Root/DIRB
No File Found
```

I have written the following code for the below. But need inputs as in how to modify it to get the required output.

**code**

```
import os.path

path = 'C:\\My\\path\\here'

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print  subdirname

    for filename in filenames:
        print os.path.join(root, filename)
```

**Actual Output**

```
DIRA
DIRB
C:\My\path\here\File1
C:\My\path\here\File2
DIRC
C:\My\path\here\DIRA\File3
C:\My\path\here\DIRA\File4
C:\My\path\here\DIRA\DIRC\File5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

path = 'Root'
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print root
    for filename in filenames:
        print filename
    if not filenames:
        print 'No File Found'
    print
```

Comment: Thanks mate . Did minor modification and got the expected result.